# Regex to remove London except London City

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex to remove London from the list except London City. Thanks in advance.

Input

```
London Heathrow, London Gatwick, London City, London Southend, London Stanstead
```

Output

```
Heathrow, Gatwick, London City, Southend, Stanstead
```

Answer (score 8):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with [negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex.

```js
var str = 'London Heathrow, London Gatwick, London City, London Southend, London Stanstead';

console.log(
  str.replace(/\bLondon\s(?!City\b)/gi, '')
)
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/vU9rF1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: the `\s` should be outside. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your regex would be

```
/London City|London\s/g
```

Match **London City** first and then **London** and then in the matcher callback method replace based on matched value

try this as well

```js
var input = "London Heathrow, London Gatwick, London City, London Southend, London Stanstead";
var output = input.replace(/London City|London\s/g, function(match){if (match == "London City") { return match } else { return "" }} );
console.log(output);
```

You can extend this regex to include other names as well (which you don't want to be replaced), for example

```
/London Heathrow|London City|London\s/g //would not replace London Heathrow and London City
```

You can make it more dynamic by using a regex constructor as

```
var itemsNotToBeReplaced = ["London Heathrow", "London City"];
var regex = new RegExp( itemsNotToBeReplaced.push("London\s").join("|"), "g" );
input.replace(regex , function(match){
   if (itemsNotToBeReplaced.indexOf(match) != -1) 
   { 
       return match ;;
   } 
   else 
   { 
       return "" ;
   }
});
```